# Eclipse IDE installation fails because it can't the find mars repository

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I have downloaded "eclipse-inst-win64.exe" from eclipse.org and while running the installation for "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" I get the error shown below:

```
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository code=1000 No repository found at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars.
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:395)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.fail(CachingRepositoryManager.java:283)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:186)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:389)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:96)
  at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:92)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1468)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:416)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Can you access http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/mars with a browser?

Comment: @aventurin yes, it open a page with the following content. You're close!

This URL is an Eclipse software repository; you must use it in Eclipse (see how).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few Eclipse bugs related to this. All the threads seem to be resolved by deleting the `$HOME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache` directory.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471528#c7

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=470900

http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/No-repository-found-exception-td175271.html

If this has made its way back into the executable file, you may need to [open a new bug](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F).

In the meantime, you may need to install the previous version, [Luna](https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/luna/sr2), instead though I would try installing the 32-bit version of Mars first.

Comment: How can we delete directory path from an .exe file. In this case "eclipse-inst-win64.exe".

Comment: @Ragavendra - Sorry, updated answer with what you should try. I think you need to open a new bug since this was something that was supposed to be fixed.